# Meteor ddp notify specific client

Tags: meteor, networking, ddp

I'm using meteor ddp (Distributed Data Protocol) to my application. Server code is written using meteor and Android client using java. 
Server code

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Users = new Mongo.Collection('testUsers');

    Meteor.publish('methodToListen', function(){
        return Users.find();
    });
}
```

Client code (https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MeteorCallback {
    private Meteor mMeteor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Meteor.setLoggingEnabled(true);
        mMeteor = new Meteor(this, "ws://192.168.137.1:3000/websocket");
        mMeteor.addCallback(this);
        mMeteor.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnect(boolean signedInAutomatically) {
        String subscriptionId = mMeteor.subscribe("methodToListen");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Exception e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataAdded(String collectionName, String documentID, String newValuesJson) {
        Log.d("DATACHANGED", "Add " + collectionName + ", " + documentID + ", " + newValuesJson);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(String collectionName, String documentID, String updatedValuesJson, String removedValuesJson) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataRemoved(String collectionName, String documentID) {

    }
}
```

So now every client that connects to server see live database updates. Is it possible to send updates only for specific client? So for example when user sign in to system it gets unique id and based on that id is it possible to send updated data?

Updated I can get information about connected clients

```
 Meteor.onConnection(function(connection) {
        console.log(connection.id + ", " + connection.clientAddress);
    });
```

[image]

So for example ip addresses could be id

Comment: How would your differentiate between the sessions of the same user, for example? What mechanism do you intend to employ in order to determine which session can receive data and which cannot? You have the user id available in the publication function.

Comment: You must read more about subscriptions...